# How to count has_and_belongs_to_many in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a simple Rails with the following structure:

```ruby
    Product
    has_and_belongs_to_many :subscribers

    Subscriber

    has_and_belongs_to_many :products
```

How can I get all products that has subscribers which is products with subscribers > 0 ?

```
def self.has_subscribers
   #subscribers > 0
end
```

Answer (score 3):

well have you tried doing,

```
@product.subscribers.count > 0
```

so you can do something like

```
def has_subscribers?
  subscribers.count > 0 
end
```

Comment: OP is looking for all products which have subscribers, not to check if a product has any subscriber. I agree, the name of the function OP used is a bit misleading.

Comment: Ah! I see.Then I believe your solution is more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

```
def self.has_subscribers
   Product.joins("LEFT JOIN products_subscribers ON products_subscribers.product_id = products.id").where("products_subscribers.product_id IS NOT NULL")
end
```

HTH

edit: I am not sure, if below will work, but you may try it:
<del>def self.has_subscribers
       Product.joins(:products_subscribers)
    end
Since, `joins` use `INNER JOIN`, it should return only those records of `products` which have a relationship with `subscribers` in the joining table.</del>

Edit 2: Just joining with joining table may not (in fact should not) work because joining table usually do not have a model.

The above is working for me, except I forgot to `GROUP` the results.

```
Product.joins("LEFT JOIN products_subscribers ON products_subscribers.product_id = products.id").where("products_subscribers.product_id IS NOT NULL").group("products.id")
```

If you are still getting `Subscribers`, then it is kinda odd. Please post your function and querying code.

Comment: This brings out only the subscribers. but does not tell me the products

Comment: That is weird. Anyways, I have updated my answer. Please try it again and post back with code if you face any issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
Product.where( '(select count(1) from products_subscribers where product_id = products.id > 0)')
```